# Save all visitors Browser Info into Session dont work

Tags: javascript, php

I want save all the visitors Browser infos in my PHP session.

I have used the same Code before in an other script and it works fine, but in this one not..

**1 Page:**

```
<?php
session_start();    
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/js/a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var client = new ClientJS();
    $("#browser_info").val(client.getBrowser() + " " + client.getBrowserMajorVersion());
    $("#os_info").val(client.getOS() + " " + client.getOSVersion());
    $("#screenPrint").val(client.getScreenPrint());
    $("#plugins").val(client.getPlugins());
    $("#isJava").val(client.isJava() + " " + client.getJavaVersion());
    $("#isFlash").val(client.isFlash() + " " + client.getFlashVersion());
    $("#isSilverlight").val(client.isSilverlight() + " " + client.getSilverlightVersion());
    $("#isMimeTypes").val(client.isMimeTypes() + " " + client.getMimeTypes());
    $("#fonts").val(client.getFonts());
});
</script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**And on the next page:**

```
$_SESSION['vic_info_browser']= $_POST['browser_info'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_os']= $_POST['os_info'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_screen']= $_POST['screenPrint'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_plugins']= $_POST['plugins'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_java']= $_POST['isJava'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_flash']= $_POST['isFlash'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_silver']= $_POST['isSilverlight'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_mime']= $_POST['isMimeTypes'];
$_SESSION['vic_info_fonts']= $_POST['fonts'];
```

My paths are also correct, anyone know whats the Problem?

> Error is: Undefined index: screenPrint

For every Session the erros comes not only `screenPrint`

Comment: How do you send data?

Comment: With Action Form POST

Comment: Post all relevant code

Comment: There's no form. You need to provide a [mcve]. (And the solution will probably be "Fix the type in the name attribute")

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: What code you want see? its too much code.

Comment: Maybe not an correct answer from me, its all within SESSION PHP, i dont send it

Comment: Show the form using POST

Comment: my form has nothing to do with my Session or the Problem.

Comment: Well that's how you send your data to initialize your Session

Comment: _“my form has nothing to do with my Session or the Problem”_ - that you did nothing to take that data from the form, send it to the server and put it into the session there, _is_ the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer to your question. In your code you're not sending any data to your PHP. A solution would be to use Ajax.

```
<?php
session_start();    
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/js/a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var client = new ClientJS();
    var browser = $("#browser_info").val(client.getBrowser() + " " + client.getBrowserMajorVersion());
    var os_info = $("#os_info").val(client.getOS() + " " + client.getOSVersion());
    var screenPrint = $("#screenPrint").val(client.getScreenPrint());
    var plugins = $("#plugins").val(client.getPlugins());
    var isJava = $("#isJava").val(client.isJava() + " " + client.getJavaVersion());
    var isFlash = $("#isFlash").val(client.isFlash() + " " + client.getFlashVersion());
    var isSilverlight = $("#isSilverlight").val(client.isSilverlight() + " " + client.getSilverlightVersion());
    var isMimeTypes = $("#isMimeTypes").val(client.isMimeTypes() + " " + client.getMimeTypes());
    var fonts = $("#fonts").val(client.getFonts());
    $.ajax({
        type      : 'POST',
        url       : 'yourphp.php',
        data      : { browser: browser, os_info: os_info, screenPrint: screenPrint, plugins: plugins, isJava: isJava, isFlash: isFlash, isSilverlight: isSilverlight, isMimeTypes: isMimeTypes, fonts: fonts  },
        success   : function(data) {

       }
    });
});
</script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And your PHP I add some verification

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['browser_info'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_browser']= $_POST['browser_info'];
}
if(isset($_POST['os_info'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_os']= $_POST['os_info'];
}
if(isset($_POST['screenPrint'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_screen']= $_POST['screenPrint'];
}
if(isset($_POST['plugins'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_plugins']= $_POST['plugins'];
}
if(isset($_POST['isJava'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_java']= $_POST['isJava'];
}
if(isset($_POST['isFlash'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_flash']= $_POST['isFlash'];
}
if(isset($_POST['isSilverlight'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_silver']= $_POST['isSilverlight'];
}
if(isset($_POST['isMimeTypes'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_mime']= $_POST['isMimeTypes'];
}
if(isset($_POST['fonts'])){
    $_SESSION['vic_info_fonts']= $_POST['fonts'];
}
```